# ASP.NET - The connection was reset. connection was time out

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, hosting, web-deployment, web-hosting

On production facing some weired behaviour, getting below error on some time but not always.

```
The connection was reset.   connection was time out.

The site could be temporary unavaiable too busy
```

Application is hosted on windows server 2008  - IIS 7.5. .NET 4

can any one share me what should i check..

Note; there is no database call on page load event. also, no posting of file.

Please suggest how i could trouble shoot or any seetings in config file.

Thank You

Comment: have you checked event viewer

Comment: Thanks for direction. it shows an error as `A worker process with process id of '2952' serving application pool 'apppp' was shutdown due to inactivity. Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes. A new worker process will be started when needed.`  Can you guide what could be the reason... is this one of possible  thing. i found this information intermaly in event log.

Comment: Not sure if that the one.
you will need to replicate the problem and watch the errors logged at that time..

Comment: No luck.. such log in event viewer is due to session or app pool recyling event..but not found any reason or log yet... please guide if any idea.

Comment: use stress tool to try to replicate.. if you can't replicate it then it is fiction :)

Comment: http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86)